# How to use Kerberos Client Authentication with NodeJS and Axios to make api call

Tags: node.js, authentication, iis, axios, kerberos

We have a use case where we are calling multiple APIs in parallel from the ReactJS UI (from browser) which is hosted in IIS web server to NodeJS application server. In NodeJS application server we have written authorization express middleware which does the authorization checks using external API to see if the logged-On user is authorized or not, If authorized then we are calling further API calls to the backend to get the data or else middleware is returning back response as the user saying user is unauthorized to make further API calls.

Now we are trying to add kerberos based authentication for authorization API call and backend further API calls.

We are getting below error when we trying to add below working Kerberos NodeJS code snippet ([Kerberos authentication in Node.js https.get or https.request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098912/kerberos-authentication-in-node-js-https-get-or-https-request/22166697)) to our authorization API call in the middleware and backend data API calls.

```
const kerberos = require('kerberos').Kerberos;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

(async () => {
    const client = await kerberos.initializeClient("HTTP@site.internal.net", {
        mechOID: kerberos.GSS_MECH_OID_SPNEGO,
    })

    const ticket = await client.step("")

    const resp = await fetch("https://site.internal.net/api/v1/hello", {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Negotiate ' + ticket
        }
    })

    console.log(await resp.json())
})();
```

We are getting this error when called in parallel above working code:

**[Error: AcquireCredentialsHandle: No credentials are available in the security package**

and 401 unauthorized request error

Also, we have noticed above errors when kerberos.initializeClient & ticket = client.step("") code is called multiple times inside the for Loop, it was failing 2 or 3 times out of 5 and was throwing above error.

Can someone please explain what is the meaning of the above error and how to avoid that error ??

Thanks in advance